# IPC::Open2 output to already open file handle as per doc example

Tags: perl, ipc

The documented example in `perldoc IPC::Open2` (read from parent STDIN and write to already open handle) is  a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Namely, parent writes a preamble to a output file, then a subprocess writes its output directly to the same file.

I've made a simple child script which reads input lines and prints to `STDERR` and `STDOUT`. The `STDOUT` being the the 'already open handle' from the parent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
##parent.pl
use IPC::Open2;

# read from parent STDIN and write to already open handle
open my $file, '>', 'outfile.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
my $pid = open2($file, "<&STDIN", "./child.pl");

# reap zombie and retrieve exit status
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
##child.pl

while(<STDIN>){
    print STDOUT "STDOUT: ",$_;
    print STDERR "STDERR: ", $_;
}
print STDERR "END OF CHILD\n";
```

An  example run of `parent.pl`:

```
Hello
^D
STDERR: Hello
STDERR: END OF CHILD
```

However, I don't see the expected "STDOUT: Hello" in the output file 'outfile.txt'

Is there some additional setup I've missed to get this example to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open my $file, '>', 'outfile.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
my $pid = open2($file, "<&STDIN", "./child.pl");
```

This will create a new pipe, and overwrite the `$file` variable with a handle refering to the read end of the pipe, closing the old file handle in the process ;-)

In order to pass an existing file handle to `open2` or `open3`, you want to use the `>&FILEHANDLE` format, but I wasn't able to figure out any way to do that when `FILEHANDLE` is a local variable, as your `my $file`.

But the undocumented `>&NUM` or `>&=NUM` forms (where `NUM` is a file descriptor number) just work:

```
open my $file, '>', 'outfile.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
my $pid = open2('>&'.fileno($file), '<&STDIN', './child.pl');
```

Example:

```
$ perl -MIPC::Open2 -e '
   open my $f, ">foo";
   open2(">&".fileno($f), "<&STDIN", "echo bar")
'; cat foo
bar
```

Comment: This is `IPC:Open2`. Plain `open` also supports `open my $f, '>file'; open my $g, '>&', $f` nicely, which `IPC::Open2` apparently does not ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip here, solved my problem.  Much easier than the manual fd duplications I was doing to get it to work!